# i am trying to use xml data for data driven testing in xunit but i am not able to iterate through the xml for different values

Tags: xml, xunit.net

how do i make xunit fetch data from an xml File**

```
[Theory]
[XmlFile("C:\\TestData\\ShipData.xml")]
public void Test(XDocument xmlXDocument)
{
//TestContents
}
```

my XML file contents are as follows**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Details>
   <ShippingCreate CustomerNumber="000123" />
   <ShippingCreate CustomerNumber="000107" />
   </Details>
```

the problem is the test doesnt iterate itself for multiple values of CustomerNumbers can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `Cavity.Data.Xml.Xunit` what you are seeing is the expected behaviour, namely that you get all of the xml data back in one go. If you specify more than one file your test will be called more than once - it will be called once per file.

Comment: thanks for the post, can u help me out as to how i can use an xml file for data-driven test so that the test runs in iteration for the number of data present

Comment: You might want to try [PropertyData] and from there manually yielding the XML records